# Unable to receive child object NULL MVC API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, class

Here is my class :

**FIRST API (POST):**

```
 public class OrderMaster 
    {
        public string DisplayorderId { get; set; }
        public string ExtOrderId { get; set; }
        public string ExtInfo { get; set; }
        public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeliveryPickup { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryPickupDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ServiceCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal ServiceChargePerc { get; set; }
        public decimal CGST { get; set; }
        public decimal SGST { get; set; }
        public decimal IGST { get; set; }
        public decimal DeliveryCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public decimal GiftWrapPrice { get; set; }
        public string OfferCouponcode { get; set; }
        public decimal OfferCouponDiscount { get; set; }
        public string GiftCouponCode { get; set; }
        public decimal GiftCouponPrice { get; set; }
        public int WalletPrice { get; set; }
        public string ShippingFullname { get; set; }
        public string ShippingEmail { get; set; }
        public string ShippingContactNo { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCity { get; set; }
        public string ShippingPincode { get; set; }
        public string ShippingState { get; set; }
        public string UserComment { get; set; }
        public string CancelRemarks { get; set; }
        public DateTime CancelDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderShippingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderCompleteDate { get; set; }
        public string CourierName { get; set; }
        public string TrackingNo { get; set; }
        public string PaymentGateway { get; set; }
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
        public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime Createddate { get; set; }
        public int TrnType { get; set; }
        public int TrnCtrlNo { get; set; }
        public List<GetOrderDtls> OrderDetails { get; set; }
                }

    public class GetOrderDtls
    {
        public int TrnCtrlNo { get; set; }
        public int TrnType { get; set; }
        public string ExtOrderId { get; set; }        
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int OrderQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal CGST { get; set; }
        public decimal SGST { get; set; }
        public decimal IGST { get; set; }
        public string OfferCode { get; set; }
        public decimal OfferDiscount { get; set; }
        public string IsGiftPack { get; set; }       
        public decimal ReturnQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal ReturnPrice { get; set; }
        public string ReturnReason { get; set; }
        public decimal DocEntDisc { get; set; }
        public decimal DiscRate { get; set; } 
    }
```

But when i am receiving some data in below code it showing `NULL` in `OrderDetails` object list :

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(OrderMaster))]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Order/OrderSave")]
        public IHttpActionResult OrderIntegartion(List<OrderMaster> order)
        {
            /*var token = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Token"];
            string webToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];
            */
            //if (token == webToken)
            //{

            string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
         }
```

The data coming from here as below :
**Second API (GET):**

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(List<Order>))]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Order/GetOrders")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOrderData()
        {
            //List<Order> OrderList = new List<Order>();

            //List<Orderdetail> OrderDList = new List<Orderdetail>();

            //var list = db.GetSalesOrderHdr().ToList();

            var list = db.GetSalesOrderHdr().ToList();
            var data = new List<Order>();

            foreach (var listdata in list)
            {
                var getorder = new Order() ;

                //Order getorder = new Order() { Orderdetails = OrderDList };

                getorder.DisplayorderId = listdata.OrderId;
                getorder.ExtOrderId = listdata.DocNo;
                getorder.ExtInfo = "";
                getorder.OrderStatusId = listdata.Status;
                getorder.BranchCode = listdata.VACompCode;
                getorder.DeliveryPickupDate = listdata.DeliveryExptdDateTime;
                getorder.Price = listdata.BTotDocValue;
                getorder.ServiceCharge = 0;
                getorder.ServiceChargePerc = 0;
                getorder.CGST = Convert.ToDecimal(listdata.BTaxComp1);
                getorder.SGST = Convert.ToDecimal(listdata.BTaxComp2);
                getorder.IGST = Convert.ToDecimal(listdata.BTaxComp3);
                getorder.DeliveryCharge = 0;
                getorder.Discount = listdata.BTotDocDisc;
                getorder.GiftWrapPrice = 0;
                getorder.OfferCouponcode = "";
                getorder.OfferCouponDiscount = 0;
                getorder.GiftCouponCode = "";
                getorder.GiftCouponPrice = 0;
                getorder.WalletPrice = 0;
                getorder.ShippingFullname = listdata.ShipToCustomerName;
                getorder.ShippingEmail = listdata.ShipToEmail;
                getorder.ShippingContactNo = listdata.PartyId;
                getorder.ShippingAddress = listdata.ShipToFullAddr;
                getorder.ShippingCity = listdata.ShipToCity;
                getorder.ShippingPincode = "";
                getorder.ShippingState = listdata.ShipToState;
                getorder.UserComment = listdata.BDocRemarks;
                getorder.CancelRemarks = listdata.RDocRemarks;
                getorder.CancelDate = listdata.RDocDt;
                getorder.OrderShippingDate = listdata.DeliveredDateTime;
                getorder.OrderCompleteDate = Convert.ToDateTime(listdata.DocDt);
                getorder.CourierName = "";
                getorder.TrackingNo = "";
                getorder.PaymentGateway = listdata.BPayModeTypeDesc;
                getorder.PaymentType = listdata.BPayModeCode;
                getorder.PaymentStatus = 0;
                getorder.Createddate = Convert.ToDateTime(listdata.DocDt);                
                getorder.TrnType = listdata.TrnType;
                getorder.TrnCtrlNo = listdata.TrnCtrlNo;

                getorder.OrderDetails  = db.GetSalesOrderHdrDtls(listdata.TrnType, listdata.TrnCtrlNo).ToList();

                data.Add(getorder);
            }

            var Message = "";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

                string UrlApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlApi"];
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(UrlApi);
                MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
                var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


                //HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<List<Order>>("/api/Order/OrderSave", data).Result;

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/api/Order/OrderSave", contentData).Result;

                Message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //Message = contentData.ToString();
            }

            return Ok(data);
        }
```

Class as below :

```
 public class Order 
    {
        public string DisplayorderId { get; set; }
        public string ExtOrderId { get; set; }
        public string ExtInfo { get; set; }
        public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeliveryPickup { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryPickupDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ServiceCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal ServiceChargePerc { get; set; }
        public decimal CGST { get; set; }
        public decimal SGST { get; set; }
        public decimal IGST { get; set; }
        public decimal DeliveryCharge { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public decimal GiftWrapPrice { get; set; }
        public string OfferCouponcode { get; set; }
        public decimal OfferCouponDiscount { get; set; }
        public string GiftCouponCode { get; set; }
        public decimal GiftCouponPrice { get; set; }
        public int WalletPrice { get; set; }
        public string ShippingFullname { get; set; }
        public string ShippingEmail { get; set; }
        public string ShippingContactNo { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCity { get; set; }
        public string ShippingPincode { get; set; }
        public string ShippingState { get; set; }
        public string UserComment { get; set; }
        public string CancelRemarks { get; set; }
        public DateTime CancelDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderShippingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderCompleteDate { get; set; }
        public string CourierName { get; set; }
        public string TrackingNo { get; set; }
        public string PaymentGateway { get; set; }
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
        public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime Createddate { get; set; }
        public int TrnType { get; set; }
        public int TrnCtrlNo { get; set; }

        public List<GetSalesOrderHdrDtls_Result> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Orderdetail
    {
        public int TrnType { get; set; }
        public int TrnCtrlNo { get; set; }
        public string ExtOrderId { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public float OrderQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal CGST { get; set; }
        public decimal SGST { get; set; }
        public decimal IGST { get; set; }
        public string OfferCode { get; set; }
        public decimal OfferDiscount { get; set; }
        public bool IsGiftPack { get; set; }
        public float ReturnQuantity { get; set; }
        public int ReturnPrice { get; set; }
        public string ReturnReason { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; } 
        public decimal DocEntDisc { get; set; }
        public decimal DiscRate { get; set; }

    }
```

Summary of above :

I m calling first api in which i passing some data as above but the child object showing NULL Values in first api but i am passing the correct data as per format in second api.

**Current Output from First API (POST) :**

```
[
  {
    "DisplayorderId": "0",
    "ExtOrderId": "S17/1",
    "ExtInfo": "",
    "OrderStatusId": 4,
    "IsDeliveryPickup": false,
    "BranchCode": "SC",
    "DeliveryPickupDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Price": 899.0000,
    "ServiceCharge": 0.0,
    "ServiceChargePerc": 0.0,
    "CGST": 0.0000,
    "SGST": 21.9300,
    "IGST": 0.0000,
    "DeliveryCharge": 0.0,
    "Discount": 0.0000,
    "GiftWrapPrice": 0.0,
    "OfferCouponcode": "",
    "OfferCouponDiscount": 0.0,
    "GiftCouponCode": "",
    "GiftCouponPrice": 0.0,
    "WalletPrice": 0,
    "ShippingFullname": "",
    "ShippingEmail": "",
    "ShippingContactNo": "1",
    "ShippingAddress": "",
    "ShippingCity": "",
    "ShippingPincode": "",
    "ShippingState": "",
    "UserComment": "",
    "CancelRemarks": "",
    "CancelDate": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
    "OrderShippingDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "OrderCompleteDate": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
    "CourierName": "",
    "TrackingNo": "",
    "PaymentGateway": "Cash",
    "PaymentType": "Rs",
    "PaymentStatus": 0,
    "Createddate": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
    "TrnType": 2100,
    "TrnCtrlNo": 1,
    "OrderDetails": [

    ]
  }
]
```

**Required Output from First API (POST) :**

```
[
  {
    "DisplayorderId": "0",
    "ExtOrderId": "S17/1",
    "ExtInfo": "",
    "OrderStatusId": 4,
    "IsDeliveryPickup": false,
    "BranchCode": "SC",
    "DeliveryPickupDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Price": 899.0000,
    "ServiceCharge": 0.0,
    "ServiceChargePerc": 0.0,
    "CGST": 0.0000,
    "SGST": 21.9300,
    "IGST": 0.0000,
    "DeliveryCharge": 0.0,
    "Discount": 0.0000,
    "GiftWrapPrice": 0.0,
    "OfferCouponcode": "",
    "OfferCouponDiscount": 0.0,
    "GiftCouponCode": "",
    "GiftCouponPrice": 0.0,
    "WalletPrice": 0,
    "ShippingFullname": "",
    "ShippingEmail": "",
    "ShippingContactNo": "1",
    "ShippingAddress": "",
    "ShippingCity": "",
    "ShippingPincode": "",
    "ShippingState": "",
    "UserComment": "",
    "CancelRemarks": "",
    "CancelDate": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
    "OrderShippingDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "OrderCompleteDate": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
    "CourierName": "",
    "TrackingNo": "",
    "PaymentGateway": "Cash",
    "PaymentType": "Rs",
    "PaymentStatus": 0,
    "Createddate": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
    "TrnType": 2100,
    "TrnCtrlNo": 1,
    "OrderDetails": [
      {
        "TrnType": 2100,
        "TrnCtrlNo": 1,
        "ExtOrderId": "S17/1",
        "Barcode": "150101787",
        "Brand": "KRISS",
        "Category": "MENS SHIRTS",
        "Product": "KRS STR F/S SHIRTS S",
        "OrderQuantity": 1.0,
        "Price": 899.0000,
        "CGST": 0.0000,
        "SGST": 21.9300,
        "IGST": 0.0000,
        "OfferCode": "",
        "OfferDiscount": 0.0000,
        "IsGiftPack": "False",
        "ReturnQuantity": 1.0,
        "ReturnPrice": 899.0000,
        "ReturnReason": "Damage",
        "DocEntDisc": 0.0000,
        "DiscRate": 0.0000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So, please look into above code and suggest the corrections.

Comment: Where are you setting `stringData`? There's no code for that in your second API action

Comment: you have` List<OrderMaster>` and` List<Order>` as two different types input musmatch

Comment: @Yogesh does this code return any value  `getorder.OrderDetails  = db.GetSalesOrderHdrDtls(listdata.TrnType, listdata.TrnCtrlNo).ToList();` in OrderDetails

Comment: @niladri  db.GetSalesOrderHdrDtls is sp tht return table with some field and i m passing parameters in it. So it will always return some data.

Comment: @yogesh did you check my answer?

Comment: yes i have checked &  updated my code as per code given.

Comment: but it is still showing null child object OrderDetails  in second object.

Answer (score 0):

your first POST accepts a argument of type `List<OrderMaster>` but you are passing a `List<Order>`. Please note that you need to return a HttpResponseMessage from the POST method as the return type is `IHttpActionResult`, currently your code dont have the return statement.

Can you try with the below code

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Order))]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Order/OrderSave")]
    public IHttpActionResult OrderIntegartion(List<Order> contentData)
    {
        /*var token = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Token"];
        string webToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];
        */
        //if (token == webToken)
        //{

      string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contentData);
      return Ok<string> (jsonString); 
     }
```

Also OrderMaster class has a property `OrderDetails` which is of type `List<GetOrderDtls>`

```
public List<GetOrderDtls> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

But Order class class has a property `OrderDetails` which is of type below

```
public List<GetSalesOrderHdrDtls_Result> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

Thus you are getting the OrderDetails property as empty array in the response.